How to invoke a script with admin rights through another script
My company is in the process of reorganizing all windows scheduler tasks that utilize PowerShell scripts. For security reasons, we are no longer allowed to use an admin domain account to call the scheduler tasks directly. However, some scripts require admin domain rights to perform their tasks.
The proposed solution is to have the Task Scheduler call a PowerShell script that accesses encrypted credentials for an admin account and uses these credentials to invoke the required script.
Here is the method I attempted to use for invoking another script:
$arguments = "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File `"$ScriptPath`""

Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments -Credential $credential -NoNewWindow

Unfortunately, this approach has not been successful so far.
Is there a reliable way to schedule PowerShell tasks that require admin privileges without directly using an admin domain account? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Is there any way you could get the tasks done with a local admin instead of a domain admin?

The domian admin has also local admin rights, I should have mentionted that. the Account that calls the Scheduler Tasks is supposed to not have any admin rights.

What I mean is, are the actions taken actually using those domain admin rights, or do you just need local admin privileges? If all you need is local admin rights, you could create a regular user on the domain and add them to a group on the domain. Then add the domain group to the "Local Administrators" group on each machine during setup. That way you could have an account that gets the job done, but doesn't have domain admin rights.
